# Using 3rd party project as dependency in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a project A depending on a project B. I downloaded the project B from a git repo, I ran "mvn package" and "mvn install" in project B so I have it in my ~/.m2/repository directory.

I tried packaging project A with the "jar-with-dependencies" and it works perfectly, but I don't want a big jar with all the dependencies.

When I put this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>ch.usi.da</groupId>
      <artifactId>paxos</artifactId>
      <version>trunk</version>
</dependency>
```

the command "mvn package" works fine but when I try to run it:

```
java -cp target/basecast-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ar.uba.dc.basecast.App
```

I got an **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/usi/da/paxos/Util** error.

I'm doing this only with maven, not using Eclipse. I want to keep it simple and learn what is happening behind the scenes, maybe Eclipse manage the classpath in a better way but I want to do it without it.

Update: I forgot to mention that this 3rd party project B has a lot of dependencies, so including its .jar file as a "lib" is not my ideal solution. I want to use maven dependencies resolution because everything is installed in my local repository.

Comment: Hm..you have created a jar-with-dependencies and everything works but you say you won't have the a jar with the dependencies ? Sounds like a contradiction in itself ? Can you explain that more in detail what your are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm not a native english speaker. When compiling with the "jar-with-dependencies" option it successfully create a big jar with everything and works perfectly. What I tried to say is I don't want this big jar as a solution, I want the user to have all the dependencies installed in the system (like using a local repo for example) and let maven do the magic.

Comment: Neither I am. No problem at all. Hm..you would like to offer your user a simple solution which the jar-with-dependencies is cause it's simple to stat etc....If you force your user to install/use Maven to get a running solution I'm the opinion that won't work...to make a more simple solution you could deliver a thing via appassembler-maven-plugin etc. but that depends on your use case...

Comment: You are right, but this project is aimed to programmers. I think my problem is I'm not an expert in Java so its disturbs me a little to compile a big "executable" (jar) and not using something like dynamic libraries previously installed in the system.

Comment: In Java you should say good bey to dll's etc (or shared libraries) because they are causing headaches..many times...apart from that most of the time you are not allowed to update a system (in real envs you are never allowed) (would change the system) (this my problem with Ruby, Python, Perl as well)...In Java you can deliver a single jar file and you get everything you need. Using JDK 9 you can deliver the whole JRE including your own app...Today you could use a Docker images to deliver the application as well in defined environment...but this is a different story...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want a fat jar (which can be for many reasons) you must first decide what other mechanism you want to use to provide a way to launch your application.   Typically you may create an executable jar with a Class-Path entry pointing to all the artifacts you use, or create a shell script that can do various sanity tricks and then assemble a classpath variable pointing to all the artifacts you use, or - on MacOS - package up an Application.  Advanced deployments may include WebStart.

A good solution at your current skill level is to use the appassembler-maven-plugin which has these coordinates:

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
```

which with a appropriate configuration section can create the scripts you need (on both Unix and Windows), put the artifacts you use in its correct spot, all as a part of your normal Maven build.

See                     http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html
 for full instructions.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Maybe I misunderstood how the repositories works in Maven, I thought it would check and use the installed jar's in the local repo. I will check appassembler-maven-plugin.

Comment: Ah, you just want to run from the maven command line yourself.  Though you would distribute your work to others.    You can use `mvn -q exec:java` for that if you put a small configuration snippet in your pom.xml file.   See the `exec-maven-plugin` section in the pom.xml for this tiny project https://github.com/ravn/dagger2-hello-world (I wrote)

Comment: Maybe I'm complicating myself avoiding Eclipse. The project B has a .classpath file (I think is generated by Eclipse) to help find its dependencies. According to this https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_use_external_dependencies Maven looks in the local repository, I don't get why my aproach doesn't work. If someone can give me a more detailed doc of Maven I will be happy.

Comment: The .classpath file is not intended for this usage by a third party so it may break any time. Maven is the current best bet for a long term build solution. I think your problem comes from that you do not understand the Classpath concept in Java fully - which is one of the big hurdles when learning Java - and therefore you do not understand why it does not work in your situation.